# How do I implement Django's password hashing while bypassing auth?

Tags: python, django

We are creating a user login and registration system and have decided to bypass Django's auth (for a few reasons, which is outside the scope of this question).

We still need encryption for our passwords and would still like to use that implemented by auth (pbkdf2_sha256, I believe). We could roll our own but would rather use Django's if we can (again, without using the auth package).

Looking at our Django install (we have 1.4.1, the latest), we found the auth folder (and a file called hashers.py) but, being new to python, aren't really sure where to go from here for encrypting our passwords.

thanks!

EDIT:

Based on the comments and answer received, I've decided to use the built-in methods and tables.

Comment: If you're new to a language/platform, going out of your way to bypass the common way of doing things is a really bad idea...

Comment: that's why we're not rolling our own

Comment: ... but you're still bypassing the normal auth package. You say it's outside the scope of this question, but I suspect it's not. If we don't know why you're not going down the simplest route, how can we know if a potential answer would go against that reason?

Comment: But if I'm using the same functions that Django uses when encrypting a password, then what's the diff? I'm not trying to be argumentative, just want to understand. I'm not trying to change any code, just trying to avoid creating extra tables in mysql for an admin panel we won't ever use

Comment: The difference is that you're creating work for yourself, for little benefit. How much cost is there in creating those extra tables? And how long do you think it will take to integrate the existing authentication libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at [the source of django's `set_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L296), you can see that it calls the [`make_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L61) function, which is probably what you are looking for.

You could then use [django's `check_password`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L40) to verify passwords.

This does add a dependency on `django.contrib.auth`, as these functions are defined in `django.contrib.auth.hashers`, but that's standard in Django, so I don't think it's an issue.
Furthermore, `django.contrib.auth.hashers` has no dependency on anything from `django.contrib.auth`.

**I can however only support the advice that was given to you in comments that you should probably be using the default django auth package** - especially given that we're talking security critical parts here.

By the way, the algorithm used to hash passwords is actually controlled by the [the `PASSWORD_HASHERS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#how-django-stores-passwords) setting.

Comment: we are using the auth package, just trying to bypass creating a bunch of mysql tables. We're leaving the django files untouched and using the functions that django uses when encrypting a password

Comment: You are not actually using the auth package, you're using two functions in there. Honestly, I don't really a strong rationale for using custom authentication rather than Django's stock auth package. Especially so if your only reason for doing so is to save you from creating a few tables (that `syncdb` would create).